# How to create multiple JSON files through the for statement and only the last line of the table is printed

Tags: python, json, for-loop

The first problem is that I have the csv data extracted through web crawling as below.
After applying the "Equipment" column of csv data to prop.value, I want to create JSON files for each row, so I want to create several json files through the for statement.

The second problem is that when prop.value is printed, only the last line, "CNC 5면 가공기", is printed. Is there a structural problem?

I am using the code for AAS pypi4.0 project.

```
name    Equipment   Size    Brand
HI_TRAX1950 CNC 수평 보링 머시닝 센터    6,000Wx1,250Lx3,500H    KIHEUNG
MIMAX_W5050 CNC 5면 가공기  10,300Wx4,000Lx6000H    KIHEUNG
Unit50  CNC 5면 가공기  10,000W × 5,000L × 3,500H   SNK




for name, equipment in zip(data['name'], data['Equipment']):

   prop= model.Property(
       id_short='Specifications',
       value_type=model.datatypes.String,
       value = equipment,
       semantic_id=model.Reference(
           (model.Key(
           type_=model.KeyElements.CONCEPT_DESCRIPTION,
           local= True,
           value='0173-1#02-BAA120#008',
           id_type=model.KeyType.IRDI),)
)
```

)

```
   submodel = Submodel(
       kind= 'instance',
       id_short= 'Technical_Data',
       identification=model.Identifier('localhost:8080/TechnicalData', 
model.IdentifierType.CUSTOM),
       submodel_element={prop},
 )
   

   obj_store: model.DictObjectStore[model.Identifiable] = model.DictObjectStore()
   obj_store.add(asset)
   obj_store.add(submodel)
   for comment in obj_store:
       filename =  f'/KL_TECH/Code_{comment}.json'
       with open(filename 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
            aas.adapter.json.write_aas_json_file(json_file, obj_store, indent = 4, ensure_ascii= False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is beacause when you use `with open(filename 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:` the method is `w` which mean it delete everything before then write the new value so you should change that to `a`
Change

```
with open(filename 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
  aas.adapter.json.write_aas_json_file(json_file, obj_store, indent = 4, ensure_ascii= False)
```

to

```
with open(filename 'a', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
  aas.adapter.json.write_aas_json_file(json_file, obj_store, indent = 4, ensure_ascii= False)
```